# Filtering Datagridview using a column in dataview using VB.Net 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am writing windows form application using Visual Studio 2010. Since I'm new to visual basic, I'm trying to filter a datagridview column by using multi values from another filteted gridview column.

In fact I'm trying to represent many_to_many relation where I have 2 main tables (student and subject), and the third is a conjunction table(stu_subj).

Is there an easy way to represent a many_to_many relation in windows form?

Or maybe something like SQL query:

```
select * from table
where [column_name] in ('a','b','c')
```

But a, b ,c. Here will be values of filtered column in the gridview!

Tried many solutions but no hope! Can someone help me doing such a task?

Comment: Are you intending to retrieve all data up front and then filter locally or do you want to retrieve child data from the database on demand?

Comment: I want to retrieve all data then do local filtering.Is there a simple way to represent m_to_m relationship like master/detail for 1_to_many relationship?